# Using GetFilesAsync efficiently (ie, with QueryOptions) on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

[This Microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994634.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) admits that `GetFilesAsync` is inefficient if you access anything but basic properties without using `QueryOptions`, however `QueryOptions` is [not implemented for Windows Phone 8.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207995). Without `QueryOptions` on my personal phone with 1800 odd photos `GetFilesAsync` takes about 12 seconds while `MediaLibrary.PictureAlbum.Pictures` takes about 0.6 seconds. Is there a way to make `GetFilesAsync` more efficient in WP8.1?

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 0):

For reading locations like the Photos library that is outside your app's own folders, there is no alternative. You can use the XNA `MediaLibrary` API for some scenarios but not all. This was one of the downsides to early convergence with Windows Desktop (where the Storage APIs typically execute much faster due to the indexer).